My game suddenly not registering clicks/touches
I am following a tutorial on making a match-3 game using Godot and GDscript. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhykrMFHOV4&list=PL4vbr3u7UKWqwQlvwvgNcgDL1p_3hcNn2&index=1)
I were met with some challenges at first, but quickly got passed them when I downloaded an older version of Godot. So now, everything has been going smoothly, until I got to part 9. He made a function that we called "func find_matches():" containing this code:
    for i in width:
        for j in height:
            if all_pieces[i][j] != null:
                var current_color = all_pieces[i][j].color
                if i > 0 && i < width - 1:
                    if all_pieces[i - 1][j] != null && all_pieces[i + 1][j] != null:
                        if all_pieces[i - 1][j].color == current_color && all_pieces[i + 1][j].color == current_color:
                            all_pieces[i - 1][j].matched = true;
                            all_pieces[i - 1][j].dim();
                            all_pieces[i][j].matched = true;
                            all_pieces[i][j].dim();
                            all_pieces[i + 1][j].matched = true;
                            all_pieces[i + 1][j].dim();
                if j > 0 && j < height - 1:
                    if all_pieces[i][j - 1] != null && all_pieces[i + 1][j + 1] != null:
                        if all_pieces[i][j - 1].color == current_color && all_pieces[i][j + 1].color == current_color:
                            all_pieces[i][j - 1].matched = true;
                            all_pieces[i][j - 1].dim();
                            all_pieces[i][j].matched = true;
                            all_pieces[i][j].dim();
                            all_pieces[i][j + 1].matched = true;
                            all_pieces[i][j + 1].dim();

after adding this, my game no longer registered any clicks/touches when running the code.
I chose to follow a few of the next parts in hopes of being able to solve the problem, but to no avail. I have made no changes to the code, and so they should be the exact same.
When running the game, this is the error message I get:
"Invalid get index '8' (on base: 'Array')"
Does anyone know what might be the problem?
As I mentioned I try to follow the next few parts (part 12 to be exact). Other than that, I looked at a few other sites and asked gpt, and got the answer that I should change this part of my code:
func make_2d_array():
    var array = [];
    for i in width:
        array.append([]);
        for j in height:
            array[i].append(null);
    return array;
To this:
func make_2d_array():
    var array = [];
    for i in range(width):
        array.append([]);
        for j in range(height):
            array[i].append(null);
    return array;


This did not help.
I've been pretty lost since, and have not been able to find solutions.
Note: This is my first time working with Godot and GDscript, so I am still learning.

Assuming the all_pieces array is dimensioned according to width and height, and without knowing the exact line causing the exception (can you confirm which one it is?), I'd imagine the offending line is:
if j > 0 && j < height - 1:
    if all_pieces[i][j - 1] != null && all_pieces[i + 1][j + 1] != null: # <---- here

Since there's no guard for i at this line, and i can take on the value width - 1, then--given my assumptions above--the call to all_pieces[i + 1][j + 1] would cause the index out-of-bounds error you're reporting.
I took a quick look at the tutorial, and it looks like you missed the part in Part 9 at 13:53 where he changes all_pieces[i + 1][j + 1] to all_pieces[i][j + 1], so I'm pretty sure what I've mentioned here is the issue you're having.
